# Why is it insecure to use an address more than once and will/can this be mitigated in future wallets or updates?

Tags: security, wallet, address

Can somebody explain to me why using addresses more than once is insecure and whether this will always be an issue or can it be mitigated in wallet or software updates? Thanks.

Comment: Using addresses more than once will remain insecure, but software updates may make it clearer for users if the send to an address that has already been used. The sender would still have to ask the recipient for a new address, though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quoting Wikipedia here, so keep that in mind. But I believe that the way they encrypt data is based on this. Thus making it quantum proof as well.

> In cryptography, a Lamport signature or Lamport one-time signature scheme is a method for constructing a digital signature. Lamport signatures can be built from any cryptographically secure one-way function; usually, a cryptographic hash function is used. Although the potential development of quantum computers threatens the security of many common forms of cryptography such as RSA, it is believed that Lamport signatures with large hash functions would still be secure in that event. Unfortunately, each Lamport key can only be used to sign a single message. However, combined with hash trees, a single key could be used for many messages, making this a fairly efficient digital signature scheme. The Lamport signature cryptosystem was invented in 1979 and named after its inventor, Leslie Lamport.

Comment: When you quote someone or something a link would be nice